# OpenID на локальном сервере

Tags: openid, denwer

Допустим есть уже готовый проект, в котором аутентификация происходит через OpenID.
Если попробовать просто завести это дело на локальной машине, в логах можно увидеть запись:

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Got no response code when fetching https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=rsed.org, referer: http://local.site/
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] CURL error (60): SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:\nerror:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, referer: http://local.site
```

Возможно ли как-то такой проект полноценно завести?

Answer (score 1):

1. какую библиотеку используете ?
2. попробуйте отключить проверку ssl в curl запросе (временно)